# Cocos2d change sprite destination

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

Alright, here we go. I have a cocos2d app, and there are targets that move toward the player. When the player moves, I would like for them to slowly change their destination toward the player again, so they aren't just moving into empty space. Is it possible to change the destination of a sprite mid-runAction?

**edit:**

This is the code in - (void)changeTargetDest

```
- (void)changeTargetDest {
    NSMutableArray* deleteArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(CCSprite* s in _targets) {
        float offX = s.position.x - player.position.x;
        float offY = s.position.y - player.position.y;
        float adjustX;
        float adjustY;
        float offDistance = sqrt(powf(offX, 2.0f) + powf(offY, 2.0f));

        if(offDistance < 15) {
            [deleteArray addObject:s];

            deaths++;
            [deathLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Deaths: %ld", deaths]];
            if(deaths == 0)
            [kdLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"K/D ratio: %ld.00", score]];
            else
                [kdLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"K/D ratio: %.2f", ((float)score / (float)deaths)]];
        }

        else {
            adjustX = offX * .99;
            adjustY = offY * .99;

            CGPoint point = CGPointMake(player.position.x + adjustX, player.position.y + adjustY);

            [s setPosition:point];
        }//else

    }//for

    for (CCSprite *target in deleteArray) {

        [_targets removeObject:target];
        [self removeChild:target cleanup:YES];                                  
    }
}
```

This works well, except for one problem. Because the new position is calculated by just taking .99 of the previous offset, the closer the target gets to the player, the more slowly it moves. How can I make its speed constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop the action and run a new action each few frames in a scheduled method. 
but the better way is to compute the position of targets according to players position and use setPosition to manualy change their positions each frame in your update method.

Comment: Exactly. Actions will lag 1 frame behind. Once you get to the situation where you would create a new move action every frame, the sprite will freeze in place and not move.

Comment: See my edit, please. With this code, the sprites do exactly what you said: they don't move at all.

Comment: In your code,  each frame you run an action and stop another action, this way the sprite will no move, actions are not good for one frame moves, if you want to move your sprites each frame you should set position manually with set position, each frame.

Comment: How exactly would I use setPosition to move the target toward the player every couple of frames?

Comment: your offX and offY indicate a vector from your player to target, and you suppose a velocity for targets, so in your update method, each frame compute the new position by calculating move in this vector direction by this velocity and set new position with setPosition.

Comment: if you want targets to move with a constant speed you should use something like this  
   `normalOffX = offX/offDistance;
    normalOffY = offY/offDistance;
    
    move = CGPointMake (speed *dt * normalOffX, speed*dt*normalOffY);
    
    [s setPosition:ccpAdd(s.position, move)];`

Comment: dt is the time elapsed from last uodate, you can take it from update method, speed is the constant speed that you want, it normalizes the distance vector, then calculates move by multiplying speed in time and then adds the move in distance vector direction to current position of s the target

Comment: dt is the parameter sent to scheduled methods like update method and shows time elapsed between two calls to the scheduled method. if you call your changeTargetDest from inside an scheduled method you can send the dt that is sent to method to your method.